Disable thumbnails for PDF in Win 11
I would like, in Windows 11, to have thumbnails on for some files (JPG etc) but off for PDFs.  So I need the general "show thumbnails" setting on, but have to remove whichever handler does PDF files. I currently use SumatraPDF as my PDF viewer.
I thought that the thumbnail handler was in the registry at classes/.pdf/shellex so I have deleted everything under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf except the key
Content Type -> application/pdf, and deleted any classids and extras under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf.
I have also cleared the explorer icon cache in %localappdata% and restarted.
No luck - the thumbnails still appear.
How can I properly remove a thumbnail handler in the registry in Windows 11?

I tried, but the thumbnails still show even if the file association is set to notepad.

Research indicates that the registry only allows enabling or disabling thumbnail handlers for all file types, and does not allow enabling or disabling this for specific file types.
In order to disable thumbnail previews for PDFs, you will need to look at the application handling the previews and see if that application has a setting that enables/disables the previews. Adobe Reader, for instance, has a setting for enabling/disabling thumbnail previews in its Preferences dialog in the General section.
SumatraPDF appears to offer the Thumbnail option during installation, but, as of a few years ago at least, did not offer a setting post-installation to control this: https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/959
It may be necessary to uninstall and then reinstall SumatraPDF and during installation tell SumatraPDF you do NOT want it serving thumbnail previews.

I've switched to the portable version, but even with sumatra uninstalled, something else must be making the thumbnails. Since this must be controlled somewhere - presumably a dll and a registry entry - it must be possible to disable it for one file type somehow by deleting the entries.

Even the various very good Windows forums do not mention any possibility of disabling thumbnails for specific file types, and so I am inclined to say there is a strong chance that is not the case.

"Research indicates" ... this can't be right. I have another windows 11 PC where I can have thumbnails for images only, not PDFs. There must be a CLSID or DLL registered somewhere, I just can't find it.

Recent SumatraPDF viewer still provides 2 of 3 historic registry sets of features in Windows Explorer. For both these registered System abilities the installer version is required and writes many entries during installation in several parts of the registry as controlled by Windows installation system.
One is file contents search so Windows can decode unsecured PDFs and find them based on content. Here on the right the search for "XRBL" returns the file(s) with that text.
Secondly SumatraPDF can supply a Viewer function that Windows may use for Outlook or Explorer Preview and Thumbnails (if the user sets them as a system preference).

Both these Extra optional Windows Explorer facilities require elevated windows installation and are options during installation. To remove either then the full application needs to be uninstalled with elevated privileges.

If you dont need either of those 2 facilities. It is much easier to (uninstall the elevated version and) use the personal portable "single exe". You can still chose that single exe as the default PDF viewer via right click a PDF.

NOTE: after uninstall Thumbnails may still be seen from history but Explorer search PDF content and PDF Preview are no longer functional. Simply the system is remembering prior data. Or another "Thumbnail" provider is functional.

Here I uninstalled both Acrobat Previewer and SumatraPDF Previewer and many Thumbnails have reverted to Edge Red Icon. however some have not !

If we copy all those files to a fresh folder the thumbnails will "disappear" (not be retained/copied to the new folder!).

The thumbnails are held in several caches and here is just the largest as nearly 45 MB in my system 45,088,768 thumbcache_1280.db it is best to use a dedicated tool rather than manual deletion. So fire up "clean disk" and delete the cache then refresh folder view.



Unfortunately, even with sumatra completely uninstalled, something else seems to be making the thumbnails :( I guess I need a way to find out what that is. Even deleting HKCR\.pdf doesn't stop it.

Clearing the icon cache could "help" them disappear?
